# powershell send-mailmessage smtp error: Denied by policy

Tags: .net, powershell, smtp

I'm using powershell's Send-Mailmessage to send mail messages and it works with local email addresses, but when I include gmail or some other mail server, I get this error message. I think, its smtp server policy problem, but I'm not administrator of this server and the smtp admin tells me that he don't know how to resolve it. Do you have any clue? Thank you!

```
Send-MailMessage : Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Denied by poli
cy.
At C:\ps\003desifrovanie.ps1:154 char:37
+                     send-mailmessage <<<<  `
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:Sm
tpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpFailedRecipientException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Send
MailMessage
```

EDIT:
So, now I know that it's Lotus Notes smtp server. The computer, from which I need to send emails is in DMZ. Network administrators and LN admins are little bit lost..

Comment: What server do you use to send mail ?

Comment: I don't know exactly, I just get an IP address and communication on port 25 is allowed. We are strongly windows oriented company, so I assume that it is windows smtp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail server you are using do not allow to relay message for the computer you are using to play the script.

Comment: The solution is in the configuration of your SMTP, your client need to be allowed to relay. If you are using a windows SMTP the relay may be blocked for your computer or your user.

Comment: So, after hours and hours of trying, our Lotus notes administrator tells me, that I need to authentificate against smtp server and furthermore, he has to allow sending emails to specific domain. Thank you

Comment: Communication between IT admin, Network admin and developpers is not so simple and it seem not to be a french exception.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I'll assume you use Microsoft Exchange server.

First off, to see if your problem is a configuration one, try sending e-mail from mail client (like ms outlook) connected to your local mail server. If it fails (should) then your script is OK and the server configuration doesn't allow for outgoing mail.

Ever since Exchange 2007 outgoing internet mail is disabled by default. You need to set up a smtp connector on the server to allow for e-mails to go to the outside world. Here's the [article](http://www.petri.co.il/configuring-exchange-2007-send-external-email.htm) that explains how to do just that.

Though you may have a connector set up, it may not just work because of a variety of other obstacles (local, ISP etc.) including group policies, exchange server relay and so on. We can't give you a solution without details, only guesses.

Also, for configuration issues I'd recommend posting on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Be carefull Outlook as an Exchange client use a MAPI client and is not using SMTP, make your test with an independant mail client like ThunderBird or blat,MSMTP (command line).